# Preencher conteúdo do div a partir de um select

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

Boa Tarde, gostaria de preencher o conteúdo de um panel a partir de um dado escolhido no select.

Meu código me parece correto, segue abaixo o que tenho até agora:

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Aqui apresentamos a os responsáveis por Hosting">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h4>Hosts - Pontos Críticos - <?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data_recente)); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Período de tempo:</label>
                    <select class="form-control"  id="tempo">
                        <option>-----</option>
                        <option value="sem">Última Semana</option>
                        <option value="mes">Último Mês</option>
                        <option value="tri">Último Trimestre</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="mostrar" value="OK"></input>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body" id="conteudo">
<!-- LOAD DA TABELA -->
</div>
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mostrar").click(function(){
    var tabID = $("#tempo").val();
    $("#conteudo").load("/var/www/html/novo/pages/capacidade/relatorios/tic/hosting/tabela_crit.php?id="+tabID);
    alert('ok');
});
```

});

tabela_crit.php:

A partir de um switch no $tabID ela faz uma consulta e então preenche uma tabela.

Aguardo respostas. Obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde, você está conseguindo chegar no script php com esse caminho (`/var/www/html/novo/pages/capacidade/relatorios/tic/hosting/tabela_crit.php`)? pode checar a aba *Network* do *Developer Tool* e ver se não retornou um 404? Pergunto isto por que este caminho é absoluto do servidor e você provavelmente está rodando um servidor local pro php, correto? Por exemplo, se você tiver usando um Apache e seu `DocumentRoot` for `/var/www/html`, você deve chamar `/novo/pages/capacidade/...`.

Comment: Era justamente esse o problema, muito obrigado, já estava desesperado aqui pq não achava erros no código.